# FastCGI NGINX permission denied error

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, fcgi, spawn-fcgi

Having trouble understanding how to correctly use FastCGI processes with NGINX. Unlike Apache, NGINX does not automatically spawn FCGI processes. So I first `apt-get fcgiwrap spawn-fcgi`.

I spawned a fcgi process by using the command

```
sudo spawn-fcgi -f /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap -s /tmp/fcgiwrap.socket
```

But I'm still getting a `502 Bad Gateway` in my browser and the following error in my NGINX error log

```
*68 connect() to unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.socket failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: git.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "git.example.com"
```

The cgi app is gitweb and I have my NGINX conf as follows:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name git.example.com;

  location /index.cgi {
    root /usr/share/gitweb;
    include fastcgi_params;
    gzip off;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $uri;
    fastcgi_param GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.socket;
  }
  location / {
    root /usr/share/gitweb;
    index index.cgi;
  }

  ssl_certificate /.../fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate /.../privkey.pem;


}
```

Follow up question: if I want to create an init script for spawning fastcgi like NGINX example [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/), do I only need to change `BIND=/tmp/fcgiwrap.socket` and `PHP_CGI=/usr/sbin/fcgiwrap` ?

Comment: You spawned a process under root. Chances are, nginx is running under another user (www-data) so it can't access the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem. I initially just created a file called `fcgiwrap.socket` and `chown www-data fcgiwrap.socket`, `chgrp www-data fcgiwrap.socket`, `chmod g+x fcgiwrap.socket`. What I didn't realize is whenever you use `spawnfcgi` to spawn a fastcgi process, it kills any previous socket and creates a new one. For me, because I wasn't under root I had to use `sudo` to run `spawnfcgi`

```
sudo spawnfcgi -a /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap -s /tmp/fcgiwrap.socket`
```

This will, like I said, create a new socket and, more importantly, under root. So just rerun `chmod,chgrp,chown` AFTER spawning a fastcgi process and you should resolve permission denied error.